# Can't get image height from slideshow on responsive design

Tags: css, image, height, slideshow

I created a slideshow for a responsive site, but cannot get the div containing the slideshow to change heights responsively. The site is http://privatedorm.businesscatalyst.com/ . 
If you wait for the slideshow to fade you can see the three red boxes. If I can get the div containing the slideshow to inherit the height of the img's they would just drop down. But, as of right now, the height is just the min-height:20px that I set.

My code is below?

Any thoughts?

HTML/Java

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="homeSlides">
        <div><img src="images/homeImages-1.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="images/homeImages-2.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="images/homeImages-3.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Show Script -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#homeSlides > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#homeSlides > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#homeSlides');
        },  5000);
    </script>

    <div id="fun">

    </div>

    <div id="practical">

    </div>

    <div id="quickLinks">

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#homeSlides {
width: 100%;
max-width:1300px;
height: inherit;
min-height: 20px;
overflow:hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 0;
}
#homeSlides > div {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height:inherit;
min-height: 20px;
overflow:hidden;
max-width: 1300px;
z-index: 0;
}
#homeSlides img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow:hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}
#fun, #practical, #quickLinks {
float: left;
width: 30%;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}
#practical, #quickLinks {
margin-left: 5%;
}
```

Comment: do you need to set the height dynamically? Will the images be different sizes? If you have different sized images in your slider then it is going to be a bit jumpy.

Comment: It would be nice since the height of the images resizes when the width of the browser window resizes. The only other way I can think to do this is to have a fixed height (which is my last resort, as I would rather have the height resize and maintain proper spacing with the other elements).